# Fazer request via FTP e retornar arquivo via HTTP

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

Estou desenvolvendo um blog e gostaria de utilizar recursos de um outro servidor via FTP. Afim de compartilhar alguns desses arquivos em minhas postagens imaginei que seria possível eu conectar o FTP dentro do PHP e retornar o arquivo desejado para o usuário, sem que precisasse copiar para o meu servidor PHP do blog. Daí vem as perguntas: o PHP precisaria baixar todo o arquivo antes de retorna-lo? Que método eu deveria usar da biblioteca [nicolab/php-ftp-client](https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client) para conseguir tal efeito?

Um exemplo mais ou menos do que penso que seria:

```
Route::get('files/{id_artigo}/{arquivo}', 'FTPController@pegarArquivo');
```

E dentro do método, essa seria a parte interessante, porém não sei como prosseguir:

```
$ftp = FTPClient();
$ftp->connect($host);
$ftp->login($user, $passwd);
// Abaixo o dummyMethod() deveria
// pegar o arquivo e armazenar em $file
// NOTA: $nome é o nome do arquivo 
$file = $ftp->dummyMethod($nome);
return $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira seria redirecionar diretamente para o arquivo:

```
header('Location: ftp://username:password@somedomain.org/somefile.zip');
```

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029340/redirecting-to-ftp-url-with-username-and-password-in-safari

Nao seria mais fácil você nesse outro servidor disponibilizar os arquivos via HTTP e só repassar o link?

Comment: é seguro fazer isso? vou tentar aqui interceptar o request para ver o que acontece

Comment: O problema é que eu preciso fazer dessa maneira por que o outro servidor não disponibiliza conexões http

Comment: Voce deve configurar um usuario somente para os arquivos publicos que voce queira disponibilizar, nao vai deixar seu usuario administrador na url. Conseguiu interceptar?

Comment: @AndersonSantos como foi resolvido?